# How to scroll the textfields when view is moved up?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad, uiscrollview

I have text fields on registration screen so when keyboard appears i am moving up the view up.Now i want to scroll through text fields when i my view is moved up.

**code for moving view up:**

```
         CGRect rect = self.view.frame;
         rect.origin.y += 220;
         rect.size.height -= 220;
         self.view.frame = rect;
```

**Here is hirecrchy**

I have `UIScrollView` at top then under `UIScrollView` i have `UIView` i call it as `contentView`.On the `contentView` i have added some text fields.So my parent view is moved up fine but i am not able to scroll the textFields up & down when i view is up. I set the following value for scrolling.

```
    self.cvHeight.constant=500;
    self.scrollView.contentSize=CGSizeMake(500, 500);
```

Here `cvHeight` is outlet of height constraint of the `contentView` & `scrollView` is outlet of `UIScrollView`

**Edit:**
When i am not moving the parentView up which is `self.view` then i am able to scroll through but if i move the parent view up then my textFields are not scrolling down they are just moving up.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using UIScrollView, this will be the best for you. Use [TPKeyboardAvoidingScrollView](https://github.com/michaeltyson/TPKeyboardAvoiding)

How to use? 
Its very simple

For use with UITableViewController classes, drop TPKeyboardAvoidingTableView.m and TPKeyboardAvoidingTableView.h into your project, and make your UITableView a TPKeyboardAvoidingTableView in the xib. If you're not using a xib with your controller, I know of no easy way to make its UITableView a custom class: The path of least resistance is to create a xib for it.

For non-UITableViewControllers, drop the TPKeyboardAvoidingScrollView.m and TPKeyboardAvoidingScrollView.h source files into your project, pop a UIScrollView into your view controller's xib, set the scroll view's class to TPKeyboardAvoidingScrollView, and put all your controls within that scroll view. You can also create it programmatically, without using a xib - just use the TPKeyboardAvoidingScrollView as your top-level view.

Answer (score 0):

**ViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface SignUp : UIViewController <UIScrollViewDelegate>
{

}
@property (nonatomic, assign) UITextField *activeTextField;
```

**ViewController.m**

```
@implementation SignUp
@synthesize activeTextField;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{


    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWasShown:) name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide:) name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];

    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}

#pragma mark - Textfield

- (void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification *)notification
{

    // Step 1: Get the size of the keyboard.
    CGSize keyboardSize = [[[notification userInfo] objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;


    // Step 2: Adjust the bottom content inset of your scroll view by the keyboard height.
    UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, keyboardSize.height, 0.0);

    _scrl.contentInset = contentInsets;
    _scrl.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;


    // Step 3: Scroll the target text field into view.
    CGRect aRect = self.view.frame;
    aRect.size.height -= keyboardSize.height;
    if (!CGRectContainsPoint(aRect, self.activeTextField.frame.origin) )
    {
        CGPoint scrollPoint = CGPointMake(0.0, self.activeTextField.frame.origin.y - (keyboardSize.height));
        [_scrl setContentOffset:scrollPoint animated:YES];
    }
}
- (void) keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification *)notification {

    UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
    _scrl.contentInset = contentInsets;
    _scrl.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;
}
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    self.activeTextField = nil;
}

- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    self.activeTextField = textField;


}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField;              // called when 'return' key pressed. return NO to ignore.
{
    if(textField == _txt_name)
    {
        [_txt_email becomeFirstResponder];
        return NO;
    }
    else if(textField == _txt_email)
    {
        [_txt_pwd becomeFirstResponder];
        return NO;
    }
    else if(textField == _txt_pwd)
    {
        [_txt_repwd becomeFirstResponder];
        return YES;
    }
    else if (textField == _txt_repwd)
    {
        [textField resignFirstResponder];
        return YES;
    }
    else
    {
        return YES;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification*)notification
{
    CGSize keyboardSize = [[[notification userInfo] objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;
    UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0,0.0,keyboardSize.height, 0.0);

    self.scrollViewPost.contentInset = contentInsets;
    self.scrollViewPost.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;

    CGRect rect = self.scrollViewPost.frame;
    rect.size.height = keyboardSize.height+_scrollViewPost.frame.size.height+84;


    if (!CGRectContainsPoint(rect, self.txtPost.frame.origin))
    {
        CGPoint scrollPoint = CGPointMake(0.0, 264+Table_Y);
        [self.scrollViewPost setContentOffset:scrollPoint animated:NO];
        self.viewPutPost.frame=CGRectMake(0, _viewPutPost.frame.origin.y-254, 320, 30);


    }
}

- (void)keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
    self.scrollViewPost.contentInset = contentInsets;
    self.scrollViewPost.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;

    self.viewPutPost.frame=CGRectMake(0,537 , 320, 30);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to move the whole view up.

Instead, change the contentOffset property of the scrollview according to your need, and increase the scrollView.contentSize accordingly when the keyboard is up.
And when keyboard is down set scrollView.contentOffset to CGPointZero and scrollView.contentSize

When your keyboard is up:

```
CGFloat yOffset = ;             //Set According to the textField
self.scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0,-yOffset);

//Increase content size to enable scrolling till the end.
CGFloat contentHeight =  self.crollView.contentSize.height + keyboardHeight;

self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(kScreenWidth, contentHeight);
```

When keyboard is down:

```
self.scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0,0);

//Increase content size to enable scrolling till the end.
CGFloat contentHeight =  self.crollView.contentSize.height - keyboardHeight;

self.crollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(kScreenWidth, contentHeight);
```

Increasing the content size will enable you to scroll the scrollview till bottom when the keyboard is up.